# Write File to Google Drive without error, but no file in Drive folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to user google drive api to transfer the files from google cloud storage to google drive. After I run this code on cloud function, there is no error thrown, but I didn't see any file in my drive folder. My drive folder is set as public accessible for testing purpose. Does anyone know this issue or have a hint about how to troubleshoot?

My source code as below:

```js
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const fs = require('fs');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const apiKey = 'xxxxxxxx';
const storage = Storage();

exports.GCS2Drive = (event, context) => {
  const auth = apiKey;
  const downloadLink = event.mediaLink;
  const fileName = event.name;
  console.log(downloadLink);
  console.log(fileName);
  const filePath = downloadLink.toString();

  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  var folderId ='XXXXXXXXX';
  var fileMetadata = {
    'name': fileName,
    parents: [folderId]
  };

  var media = {
    mimeType: 'text/csv',
    body: fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  };

  drive.files.create({
    resource: fileMetadata,
    media: media,
    fields: 'id'
  },function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(file.id);}
  }
  )

  console.log(`complete`);
};
```

Comment: Your Cloud Function is exiting before the file is created. JavaScript is asynchronous.  You need to wait for `drive.files.create()` to complete.

Comment: @JohnHanley i'm not super clear about the asy part. Do you mean I need to add wait async before drive.files.create()?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do, is to include `the drive.files.create()` method in a promise.

A Promise object represents a value that may not be available yet, but will be resolved at some point in the future. It allows you to write asynchronous code in a more synchronous way.

Below I am including some articles that explain detailed how to use promises.

[How to write Promises in JavaScript](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/truly-understanding-promises-in-javascript-cb31ee487860)

[JavaScript Promises](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-write-a-javascript-promise-4ed8d44292b8/)

Let me know if this is helpful.